# Do individual countries control transit zone law?

Tags: law, international, foreign-policy, policy

I have a question about transit zones and their laws.

Do individual countries control transit zone law? Or are they covered by international law, since they are international zones?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but [this interview](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=198444067) may answer some of your questions.

Comment: @Sam-i-am - Good edit.  Definitely clearer now.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too broad" because there are several distinct questions here.

Comment: In addition to the point by @indigochild, this question is too broad because it depends on which transit zone. When it comes to transitzones in airports it's pretty clear, but when it comes to the areas in between states (i.e. on the border) it may be different on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2):

> Do individual countries control transit zone law? Or are they covered by international law, since they are international zones?

The former with a twist. Individual countries [control transit zones](https://elpais.com/elpais/2013/06/27/inenglish/1372357556_111094.html) on their territory, as in these are sovereign territory rather than international territory. They're just buffer zones where you keep visitors around until they've effectively crossed the border.

The twist is that, yes, there are international treaties that relate to them -- see e.g. the ones that relate to [aviation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_law). Further, the laws that apply to them continue to evolve. See for instance [this paper on Special International Zones](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3271942), which are glorified mobile international transit zones.

Comment: "on their territory": this alludes to the widely-held misconception that transit zones are in fact international territory.  It might improve this answer to make that point more explicit.  Even the "no man's land" on a land border is not international territory, though there are cases where there is a "condominium" zone with shared sovereignty.  Antarctica is international territory, I suppose, as are international waters.

Comment: @phoog: the linked article is rather explicit on this, but I see your point and will update.

Comment: @phoog The Antarctic situation is slightly more complicated than you suggest. There certainly are sovereignty claims, it's just nobody seems to support anyone else.

Comment: @origimbo yeah, that's why I said "I suppose": I'm not up to speed on the legal status of Antarctic territory.